# Solving Cubic root equation

Tags: polynomials, cubics

This is the equation I have
$$
[\frac{k^3\alpha^2x_{N-1}^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1}^3 + (k^2\alpha x_{N-1}^2 - \frac{k}{2}x_{N-1}^2)\lambda_{N-1}^2] - \frac{m}{2}(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 = 0
$$
I am required to factorize it to find the value of $\lambda_{N-1}$. I would normally use long division to find cubic roots. But in this case, using that would be too complicated. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Write it as $\Pi \lambda_{N-1}^{3} + \Sigma \lambda_{N-1}^{2}-\Phi=0$ and see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function - note that in the wiki article, here $c=0$.

Comment: Why change the coefficients to $\Pi, \Sigma$ or $\Phi$?

Comment: How can long division help you find the roots ???

Comment: I usually use long division to factorise the polynomial to obtain the roots.

Comment: How can long division help you factorize the polynomial ??? It can be used for deflation, not for root finding.

Comment: I've worded that wrongly. Use long division to reduce the cubic polynomial to a quadratic polynomial after finding the first root of the equation.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini For ease of computation, simply lifting the methods of solving cubics would elicit a solution in $\Pi, \Sigma$ & $\Phi$. Then sub those terms back in at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a right way to solving this, but I managed to factorize it to solve it.
$$
[\frac{k^3\alpha^2x_{N-1}^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1}^3 + (k^2\alpha x_{N-1}^2 - \frac{k}{2}x_{N-1}^2)\lambda_{N-1}^2] - \frac{m}{2}(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 = 0
$$
$$
[(kx_{N-1}^2)\lambda_{N-1}^2](\frac{k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} + k\alpha -\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{m}{2}(x_N - x_{N-1})^2
$$
$$
\lambda_{N-1}^2 = \frac{m}{2k}\frac{(x_N - x_{N-1})^2}{x_{N-1}^2}\\ or \\ (\frac{k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} + k\alpha -\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{m}{2}(x_N - x_{N-1})^2
$$
from where i can solve this for $\lambda_{N-1}$